# JSONException: No value for id

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

It reads and writes fine from the database but gives the JSONException error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the error message you get, it will give some indication of where it is going wrong.

Comment: W/System.err(18921): org.json.JSONException: No value for id

Comment: Do you not get any more of a stack trace?

Comment: Jon, yes I post the error messages to the code. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't got my line numbers on but its line 84 of your LoginActivity probably this statement `db.addUser(json.getString(KEY_ID), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));`  The error as others have pointed out is the `json.getString(KEY_ID)` statement.  I suggest first printing out the json to make sure it is what you expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error happens in getter functions of a `JSONObject` and it means that you are trying to retrieve a value from the JSONObject using an id that doesn't exist in the JSONObject. Before retrieving a value, check if it actually exists in the `JSONObject` by the `has(String name)` method or using the opt methods. For more information about the `JSONObject` class see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

**EDIT** From your error log, the error triggers in a `getString` method inside the `OnClickListener` of your `Button` named `btnRegister`.